# Get different result with the same regex pattern in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I have a string from INI file like this below.

```
string inistr = "[sectionA]KeyName_1=10.01\r\nKeyName_2=20.2\r\nKeyName_3=15.6\r\n[sectionB]KeyName_4=10.01\r\nKeyName_5=20.2\r\nKeyName_6=15.6\r\n"
```

Then first I try to split into 2 sections by regex and I had tried this regex and gotten the result below from [here](https://regex101.com/r/1vmAZQ/1).

[image]

Next, I started to try it by C# and I used ***Regex.Matches*** to realize it.

```
var sections = Regex.Matches(inistr, @"^\[.*\](\r|\n|\r\n)[a-zA-Z0-9_=.\r\n]*");

if(sections.Count != 0)
{
    foreach(var sect in sections)
        Console.WriteLine(sect.ToString());
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("Cannot Find Any Section...");
```

However, I found it could not find any section by the regex pattern.

Then I found the pattern could get sections if I didn't use '**^**', like below.

```
//var sections = Regex.Matches(inistr, @"^\[.*\](\r|\n|\r\n)[a-zA-Z0-9_=.\r\n]*");
var sections = Regex.Matches(inistr, @"\[.*\](\r|\n|\r\n)[a-zA-Z0-9_=.\r\n]*");
```

But I don't know why it coundn't catch sections if I used '**^**'.

Why are the results different between C# and [here](https://regex101.com/r/1vmAZQ/1)?

Comment: Your online tool is using the PHP variant of regex, which is different from the C# variant. If you want to test a regex, you need to use a .NET-compatible tool. See duplicate.

Comment: i tried your code, but no matter `^` exists or not, no match. and why not use some ini package to parse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `RegexOptions.Multiline` option so that `^` matches at the beginning of a line (instead of the beginning of the string). So your matching code should be like:

```cs
var sections = Regex.Matches(
    inistr, @"^\[.*\](\r|\n|\r\n)[a-zA-Z0-9_=.\r\n]*", RegexOptions.Multiline
);
```

Comment: Thanks! you resolved my confusion about it! Is it like "/gm" in regex?